# Extract lines matching a pattern from all text files in a folder to a single output file

Tags: powershell, foreach, filtering, get-childitem, select-string

I am trying to extract each line starting with "%%" in all files in a folder and then copy those lines to a separate text file. Currently using this code in PowerShell code, but I am not getting any results.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "folder" -Filter *.txt
foreach ($file in $files)
{
if ($_ -like "*%%*")
{
Set-Content "Output.txt" 
}  
}
```

Comment: Used this code, I am doing something really wrong here
$files = Get-ChildItem "FOLDER" -Filter *.txt
foreach ($file in $files)
{
(Select-String -Path *.txt -Pattern '^%%').Line | Set-Content "Output.txt"
}

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think that mklement0's suggestion to use `Select-String` is the way to go. Adding to his answer, you can pipe the output of `Get-ChildItem` into the `Select-String` so that the entire process becomes a Powershell one liner.

Something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem "folder" -Filter *.txt | Select-String -Pattern '^%%' | Select -ExpandProperty line | Set-Content "Output.txt"
```

Answer (score 10):

The `Select-String` cmdlet offers a much simpler solution (PSv3+ syntax):

```
(Select-String -Path folder\*.txt -Pattern '^%%').Line | Set-Content Output.txt
```

- `Select-String` accepts a filename/path pattern via its `-Path` parameter, so, in this simple case, there is no need for `Get-ChildItem`.

  - If, by contrast, you input file selection is recursive or uses more complex criteria, you can pipe `Get-ChildItem`'s output to `Select-String`, as demonstrated in [Dave Sexton's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41055543/45375).
  - Note that, [according to the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-String), `Select-String` by default assumes that the input files are UTF-8-encoded, but you can change that with the `-Encoding` parameter; also consider the *output* encoding discussed below.
- `Select-String`'s `-Pattern` parameter expects a *regular expression* rather than a wildcard expression.
  `^%%` only matches literal `%%` at the *start* (`^`) of a line.
- `Select-String` outputs `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]` *objects* that contain information about each match; each object's `.Line` property contains the full text of an input line that matched.
- `Set-Content Output.txt` sends all matching lines to single output file `Output.txt`

  - `Set-Content` uses the system's legacy Windows codepage (an 8-bit single-byte encoding - even though the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?) mistakenly claims that *ASCII* files are produced).
    If you want to control the output encoding explicitly, use the `-Encoding` parameter; e.g., `... | Set-Content Output.txt -Encoding Utf8`.
  - By contrast, `>`, the output redirection operator *always* creates UTF-16LE files (an encoding PowerShell calls `Unicode`), as does `Out-File` *by default* (which can be changed with `-Encoding`).
    Also note that `>` / `Out-File` apply PowerShell's default formatting to the input objects to obtain the string representation to write to the output file, whereas `Set-Content` treats the input as *strings* (calls `.ToString()` on input objects, if necessary).  In the case at hand, since all input objects are already strings, there is no difference (except for the character encoding, potentially).

---

As for **what you've tried**:

- `$_` inside your `foreach ($file in $files)` refers to a *file* (a `[System.IO.FileInfo]` object), so you're effectively evaluating your wildcard expression `*%%*` against the input file's *name* rather than its *contents*.
- Aside from that, wildcard pattern `*%%*` will match `%%` *anywhere* in the input string, not just at its *start* (you'd have to use `%%*` instead).
- The `Set-Content "Output.txt"` call is missing *input*, because it is not part of a pipeline and, in the absence of pipeline input, no `-Value` argument was passed.

  - Even if you did provide input, however, output file `Output.txt` would get *rewritten as a whole* in *each iteration* of your `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls *.txt | %{
$f = $_
  gc $f.fullname | {
     if($_.StartWith("%%") -eq 1){
        $_ >> Output.txt
     }#end if
  }#end gc
}#end ls
```

Alias

```
ls - Get-ChildItem
gc - Get-Content
% - ForEach
$_ - Iterator variable for loop
>> - Redirection construct
# - Comment
```

http://ss64.com/ps/

Answer (score 1):

First you have to use

> Get-Content

in order to get the content of the file. Then you do the string match and based on that you again *set the content* back  to the file. Use **get-content** and put another loop inside the **foreach** to iterate all the lines in the file.

I hope this logic helps you